# Submit button doesn't fil full width of list item in FF

Tags: html, css, firefox

Here is a JSFiddle link to some code: http://jsfiddle.net/8dtbexy3/1/

```
<style>
    .buttons-dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list.expanded {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0 1px;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background: #fff;
        bottom: 2.6em;
        right: -1px;
        display: block;
    }
    .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li {
        position: relative;
        height: 2em;
        line-height: 2em;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        border-bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li input[type="submit"] {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 20px;
        text-align: left;
        background: none;
        border: 0;
        color: #000;
        outline: none;
    }
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        /* Fix dropdown buttons width specially for FF */
        .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li input[type="submit"] {
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li input[type="submit"]:hover {
        background: #e8e7e5;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li input[disabled="disabled"] {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li input[disabled="disabled"]:hover {
        background: none;
        cursor: default;
    }
</style>
<div style="margin:200px 300px;" class="buttons-dropdown">
    <a class="buttons-dropdown-opener">Upload</a>
    <ul class="buttons-dropdown-list expanded">
        <li><input value="Upload Product Template" formaction="upload" type="submit"></li>
        <li><input value="Upload ZIPPED Product Templates" formaction="uploadZipped" type="submit"></li>
        <li><input disabled="disabled" value="Upload Media Zip" formaction="uploadMediaZip" type="submit"></li>
        <li><input value="Talend Upload" formaction="uploadTalend" type="submit"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do - is to create a dropdown list of items, where each of item supposed to be submit button. I've cut the piece of code just to illustrate the problem.

The problem - in FIREFOX submit button doesn't fit 100% width of list item, so when you will mouse hover on it - only part of it became grey...

Any ideas how to fix this with ONLY CSS changing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding fixed CSS width (or min-width) to container solved the problem.

```
.buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list.expanded {
        width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply a css rule to the li:hover element instead of the input?

```
.buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li:hover {
        background: #e8e7e5;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

UPDATE:

change the :hover rule to:

```
.buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li:not(.disabled):hover {
        background: #e8e7e5;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

and in the li element add the disabled class to it:

```
<li class="disabled"><input disabled="disabled" value="Upload Media Zip" formaction="uploadMediaZip" type="submit"></li>
```

How does it sound to you?

Comment: because then I wouldn't know if list item is disabled or not

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion @Bonomi's answer is good for your situation.

```
/* Target li not input element */
.buttons-dropdown .buttons-dropdown-list li:hover {
    background: #e8e7e5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But I saw your comment under his answer that you said I wouldn't know if the input is enable or not. For this purpose you can use this tricks.

*Trick #1*: Consider an `enabled` class for all `li` elements which have an enabled `input` element.

*Trick #2:* Use jQuery `:has()` selector. In your case you probably need something like this:

```
$('li:has(input:not([disabled="disabled"]))').hover(function() {
    // Apply hover styles on the li element
},
function() {
    //  Clear hover style on the li element
});
```

And suppose you want to obtain a reference to the hovered input in your JS codes, For this you can try this code:

```
$('li:hover input').someMetod();
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

`:has()` selector is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: well it will work for sure, but I'm confused why it won't work currently?

Comment: @Vytalyi Please see my updated post. As a note, in my opinion the first way is much better than second one because it's more straightforward.